# Form only Posts on the second click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, post, confirm

I have a problem.
I'm using a form to create something, but when i click to submit the form, I call a js function that changes a routedvalue. This works fine, but the first time I try to submit the form, only the routed value changes. The second time I try to submit the form, the Form does post with the correct value.

How can I change this code so that the form changes the routedvalue and does Post(with the correct value) on the First click.

FORM:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial", "Functiebeschrijving", null,  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Functiebeschrijving", OnBegin = "return ConfirmDone()", OnSuccess = "handleSuccess" }, new { @id = "frmID" }))
```

{

JS:

```
    function ConfirmDone() {
        var form = document.getElementById('frmID');
        if (confirm("This form saves default as Concept, would you like to save it as completed? 1 = Completed, 2 = Concept")) {
            //option 1: save as completed
            form.setAttribute('action', addDataToUrl(form.getAttribute('action'), 'sopt', 1));
        }
        else {               
            //Option 2: save as concept
            form.setAttribute('action', addDataToUrl(form.getAttribute('action'), 'sopt', 2));
        }
    }

    function addDataToUrl(url, name, value) {
        var sep = url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
        return url + sep + name + '=' + value;

    }
```

EDIT:

This is what i get in Fiddler2 after the first click

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'sopt' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial(Evaluatietool.Models.NieuweFunctiebeschrijvingViewModel, Int32)' in 'Evaluatietool.Controllers.FunctieBeschrijvingController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters*

the second click resulsts in 0 errors.

Comment: I'n not sure, but can you try to use `form.submit();` at the end of your `ConfirmDone()` function?

Comment: does not help, tried it before, return true does not work either